Pandas и анализ DataFrame .csv файла
Подскажите как с помощью pandas отфильтрофать .csv файл с данными по алгоритму:
Пример исходного файла:



data
name
age
product




01.01.2020 2:59
John
18
tomat


01.01.2020 3:28
Karl
35
tomat


02.01.2020 1:58
Karl
35
tomat


02.01.2020 19:58
Jet
50
banan


03.01.2020 1:00
John
18
tomat


03.01.2020 1:00
John
18
apple


04.01.2020 15:45
Jet
50
banan


04.01.2020 10:15
Jet
50
tomat


10.01.2020 7:15
Jet
50
tomat


12.01.2020 9:00
Kim

apple


15.01.2020 7:15
Jet
50
tomat



В таблице могут присутствовать пустые ячейки в столбце Age.
Готовое решение:



name
age
product
date
quantity




John
18
tomat
01.01.2020 2:59, 03.01.2020 1:00
2


John
18
apple
03.01.2020 1:00
1


Karl
35
tomat
01.01.2020 3:28, 02.01.2020 1:58
2


Jet
50
banan
02.01.2020 19:58, 04.01.2020 15:45
2


Jet
50
tomat
04.01.2020 10:15, 10.01.2020 7:15, 15.01.2020 7:15
3


Kim

apple
12.01.2020 9:00
1



С последующим импортом в тот же .csv или .xlsx

здесь принято показывать свои попытки решения задачи.

Вот вам еще вариант с pivot_table:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("1.csv")
res = df.fillna("").pivot_table(index=["name","age","product"],
                                values=["data"], aggfunc=list
                               ).reset_index()
res["quantity"] = res["data"].str.len()

res:
   name   age product                                               data  quantity
0   Jet  50.0   banan               [02.01.2020 19:58, 04.01.2020 15:45]         2
1   Jet  50.0   tomat  [04.01.2020 10:15, 10.01.2020 7:15, 15.01.2020...         3
2  John  18.0   apple                                  [03.01.2020 1:00]         1
3  John  18.0   tomat                 [01.01.2020 2:59, 03.01.2020 1:00]         2
4  Karl  35.0   tomat                 [01.01.2020 3:28, 02.01.2020 1:58]         2
5   Kim         apple                                  [12.01.2020 9:00]         1

в столбце data я оставил список - дальше сами разберетесь, что с ним делать, если вам нужна просто строка с данными через запятую.

Кстати да, pivot-ы же всякие, никак не научусь ими пользоваться, тут вполне к месту.

последнюю строку кода можно опустить, если сделать aggfunc=[list,len]

@АлексейР я сначала так было и сделал, правда с конкатенацией списка в строку, но подумал, что переименование столбцов вряд ли сократит код.

Я вам покажу заготовку, вам её нужно будет допилить. Тут всё слишком просто, я так понимаю, это у вас задание, так вот всё-таки постарайтесь его выполнить самостоятельно.
Но прежде должен заметить:

Это называется не фильтрация, а группировка
Правильно поставить задачу - это половина дела, а то и 90% в каких-то случаях, написать код по хорошо поставленной задаче обычно не сложно
Постановку задачи вы вообще не описали, но в общем тут можно догадаться

Просто группируем данные по колонкам Имя, Возраст и Продукт и потом аггрегируем.
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
data    name    age product
01.01.2020 2:59 John    18  tomat
01.01.2020 3:28 Karl    35  tomat
02.01.2020 1:58 Karl    35  tomat
02.01.2020 19:58    Jet 50  banan
03.01.2020 1:00 John    18  tomat
03.01.2020 1:00 John    18  apple
04.01.2020 15:45    Jet 50  banan
04.01.2020 10:15    Jet 50  tomat
10.01.2020 7:15 Jet 50  tomat
12.01.2020 9:00 Kim     apple
15.01.2020 7:15 Jet 50  tomat"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\t')
df.groupby(['name', 'age', 'product']).agg({'product': 'count', 'data': ', '.join})

Вывод:
                        product data
name    age product     
Jet     50.0    banan   2   02.01.2020 19:58, 04.01.2020 15:45
                tomat   3   04.01.2020 10:15, 10.01.2020 7:15, 15.01.2020 ...
John    18.0    apple   1   03.01.2020 1:00
                tomat   2   01.01.2020 2:59, 03.01.2020 1:00
Karl    35.0    tomat   2   01.01.2020 3:28, 02.01.2020 1:58

Вам нужно будет сделать самостоятельно:

Результат аггрегации через reset_index сделать колонками
Переименовать колонку с количеством

Но основное я вам показал: группировка и аггрегация.
P.S. Неправильно сначала поставил разделитель, дата у вас уже нормальная, не нужно ничего склеивать )

Благодарю за помощь и подсказки  что читать\изучать. Это самовыданное задание) В экселе данную группировку научился делать решил всё автоматизировать.

@Tetr чтобы отметить вопрос решённым, нужно выбрать наиболее полезный ответ и принять его, для этого нужно поставить зелёную галочку слева от него.
